# Запуск старого проекта

Tags: php

В руки попал очень старый проект, судя по синтаксису - примерно из 2013. Нормально пытаюсь запустить на PHP 5.6.35, но начал вываливаться с `syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)` на этом куске кода (6-я строка, где закрывающий php-тег):

```
    <?
    if (  $domainauto==1  ) { ?><a class="<?php print $iwayprefix; ?>_pathway_link" href='index2.php'>Главная</a><?php print print_pathwayspliter_admin(); print print_pathwayspliter_admin(); }
    else if (  $domainauto==0  ) { ?>Главная<?php print print_pathwayspliter_admin(); print print_pathwayspliter_admin(); }
    for ($iii=0; $iii<count($icatway); $iii++ ){
        if (  $icatway[$iii]->url==''  ){
            ?><span id="iclast" onclick="javascript:cht(<?=ggri("t");?>);" class="<?php print $iwayprefix; ?>_pathway_name"><?php print $icatway[$iii]->name; ?></span><?
        }
        else {
            ?><a class="<?php print $iwayprefix; ?>_pathway_link" href='<?php print $icatway[$iii]->url; ?>'><?php print $icatway[$iii]->name; ?></a><?
        }
        if (  $iii<(count($icatway)-1)  ) {
            print print_pathwayspliter_admin();
        }
    }

    ?>
```

В проекте включены короткие теги (`ini_set('short_open_tag', 'on');`), но что еще нужно включить чтобы парсер обрабатывал закрывающие теги внутри условных операторов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что *ini_set* не активирует директиву short_open_tag.

Директива short_open_tag является **PHP_INI_PERDIR**, что означает что она может быть установлена только с помощью *php.ini*, *.htaccess* или *httpd.conf* (с PHP 5.3), установка через ini_set возможна только для директив **PHP_INI_USER**, **PHP_INI_ALL**.

---

[Описание встроенных директив php](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php)

[Описание режимов PHP_INI_*](http://php.net/manual/ru/configuration.changes.modes.php)

[Описание файла конфигурации php.ini](http://php.net/manual/ru/configuration.file.php)

Comment: Помимо short_open_tag, в .htaccess устанавливались следующие параметры интерпрератора:

php_value short_open_tag 1

php_value register_globals 0

php_value display_errors 0

php_value magic_quotes_gpc 1

Проект удалось развернуть только когда скопировал php.ini с рабочего сервера. Установки short_open_tag было недостаточно (валилось спустя 20 строк с такой же ошибкой)